# What is purpose of giving estimatedRowHeight a specify value?

Tags: swift

I know that to enable self-sizing we need to set to `estimatedRowHeight` a specific value but I can't get the purpose of doing it. For example, what if I set the property to 600 but my actual cell size is only 40 ?

In my projects, I always set a random value to it and it works well.

Please explain to me, I'm very curious. Thank a lot.

Answer (score 2):

It is used to estimate the height of the content view (not the table view's size itself). Table view needs to know the height of its content to allow scrolling smoothly without actually loading all the cells. If your `estimatedRowHeight` is quite different from the real cell's height, then when you try to scroll you may see the scroll indicator flickers. Or when you try to reload table view, the high possibility that you may see the cells appears in a weird way and with unexpected animations.

Answer (score 1):

It helps auto layout prepare an initial value for the display until the actual height is being calculated by the constraints you set to the elements inside the cell from top to bottom